# Hello world example for file recovery?

Tags: principles, file-recovery

How can I recover a file that's already deleted(how does those disk recovery tools do the job)?

Is there an example to follow no matter which fs or os?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe take a look at [Rawdisk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rawdisk) will help.